# Cannot resolve symbol 'cat_item_layout' in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm currently trying to create a category section in my android app following a few tutorials that I found online.
When i'm trying to connect the layout using the LayoutInflater.from it gives me this error:

> cannot resolve symbol 'cat_item_layout' | create layout resource file ... (but it already exists)

Somebody knows why?

Down below you can find the peace of code that i wrote:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v;
    if(convertView == null){
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cat_item_layout,parent,false);
    }
    else{
        v = convertView;
    }

    return v;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code as far as I can tell. Could you specify your situation a little bit more and explain who is the parent ViewGroup? The error could stem from the parent.getContext() part.

Comment: Also, try copy&pasting the whole error from console/logcat. Maybe you're getting an explanation in there and right now I can't see any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may occur due to cruncher having some error please cross check and make sure your `cat_item_layout` has no error in its listing eg. missing resource that are defined within it else you need to do a `Build -> Rebuild Project`

Answer (score 0):

Try File->Invalidate caches/Restart